# p-integrability of characteristic function for a random vector with exponential moments

Tags: probability, lp-spaces, characteristic-functions

Take a probability measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and assume

$$\int e^{\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y} \, d\nu(x,y) < +\infty \quad \forall (\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2.$$

Assume that $\nu$ has a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Is there any way to know if the characteristic function of $\nu$ is in some $L^p$ space?

Comment: If $\nu$ is the delta measure at $(0,0)$ then the characteristic function is identically $1$ so it does not belong to any $L^{p}$.

Comment: doesn't the phrase "Assume that ν has a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure" exclude the delta measure?